# Delete Listview item with Async Class?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-asynctask

I've got my listview which displays my database entries from my localhost db. I want to delete a row every time I click the listview item. Then the counter updates and the list is refreshed. Any ideas?

Class:

```
public class ViewAllLocations extends ListActivity {

String id;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> profileList;

// url to get all products list
private static String url_all_profile = "http://MYIP:8888/android_connect/get_all_location.php";
// url to delete product
private static final String url_delete_profile = "http://MYIP:8888/android_connect/delete_location.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_LATITUDE = "latitude";
private static final String TAG_LONGITUDE = "longitude";


// products JSONArray
JSONArray userprofile = null;

TextView locationCount;
int count = 0;
Button deleteLocation;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_all_locations);
    // Hashmap for ListView
    profileList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    deleteLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deleteLocation);
    locationCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationCount);

    // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadAllLocation().execute();



  // Get listview
        ListView lo = getListView();
        lo.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                new DeleteLocation().execute();
                profileList.remove(position);
            }
        });
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteLocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


        /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewAllLocations.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Location...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Deleting product
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        // Check for success tag
        int success;
        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));

            // getting product details by making HTTP request
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    url_delete_profile, "POST", params);

            // check your log for json response
            Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

            // json success tag
            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                // product successfully deleted
                // notify previous activity by sending code 100
               // Intent i = getIntent();
                // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                //setResult(100, i);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }


    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
        pDialog.dismiss();

    }

}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
 * */
class LoadAllLocation extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ViewAllLocations.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Locations. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * getting All products from url
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_profile, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All Profiles: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                userprofile = json.getJSONArray(TAG_LOCATION);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < userprofile.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = userprofile.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String latitude = c.getString(TAG_LATITUDE);
                    String longitude = c.getString(TAG_LONGITUDE);


                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                    map.put(TAG_LATITUDE, latitude);
                    map.put(TAG_LONGITUDE, longitude);


                    // adding HashList to ArrayList
                    profileList.add(map);
                }
            } else {
                // no products found
                // Launch Add New product Activity
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        UserLocation.class);
                // Closing all previous activities
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                /**
                 * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                 * */


                 ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        ViewAllLocations.this, profileList,
                        R.layout.locationitem, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                        TAG_LATITUDE, TAG_LONGITUDE},
                        new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.latitude, R.id.longitude});
                // updating listview
                setListAdapter(adapter);
                locationCount.setText(""+profileList.size());

            }
        });

    }

}
```

Comment: @AnubianNoob I can't get it to match with the listview? Before I added the button, I had an onItemClickListener and ran the async execution, but I wouldn't get an error it was just blank and couldn't delete anything? Any ideas based on my code what I need to do with a button now? Plus Im not sure how to get the selections link and delete them whilst refreshing the listview and updating the counter?

Answer (score 0):

When you get successfully delete product you also need to remove that product from your list.

Using `yourList.remove(position)` and get your list refresh.

Comment: In,if product 
   if (success == 1) {
             profileList.remove(position);
 
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Deleted",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }

Comment: @Divya...it doesn't work, can't recognise position...My listview isn't really referenced and is passed through the async class...in my xml it has id/list

Comment: I re-edited the question, so make it easier, basically I was a listener on my listview so overtime I click it calls my async class, and the the items are deleted and updated...

Comment: See my code, I changed it... My listview lo - I can't assign the resource id/list to it?

Comment: Sorry,can't get your exact intention..Why do you want to use async exactly for?
and to delete the entry from listview , arraylist.remove(position) should work..and to reflect the changes,you need to refresh listview's adapter using notifyDataSetChanged() method..

Comment: I just want to click on a item and it will call my async task that deletes the position, the async is to delete the item from my database (localhost). So in an OnClickListener it will call my async and the tasks should be removed and updated from the listview and my db. Hope that helps? Any ideas?